# Dart the operator [] isn't defined for 'Future<Map<String,Object>> Function(String)'

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, undefined

I'm trying to set up Auth0 for my Flutter app from [this demo](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/), but I ran into this issue. I've only been using Flutter for a little while, and I fixed a few errors, but can't fix this one. I checked for other answers here, and tried the documentation too. The error message is;

`The operator [] isn't defined for 'Future<Map<String,Object>> Function(String)'`

This is the method with the error;

```
Future<void> loginAction() async {
    setState(() {
      isBusy = true;
      errorMessage = '';
    });

    try {
      final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
      await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
          AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI,
          issuer: 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN',
          scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
          promptValues: ['login']
        ),
      );

      Map<String, Object> parseIdToken(String idToken) {
        final parts = idToken.split(r'.');
        assert(parts.length == 3);

        return jsonDecode(
            utf8.decode(base64Url.decode(base64Url.normalize(parts[1]))));
      }
      
      Future<Map<String, Object>> getUserDetails(String accessToken) async {
        final url = 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN/userinfo';
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          url,
        ));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {
          throw Exception('Failed to get user details');
        }
      }
      
      await secureStorage.write(
          key: 'refresh_token', value: result!.refreshToken);

      setState(() {
        isBusy = false;
        isLoggedIn = true;
        name = parseIdToken['name'];
        picture = getUserDetails['picture'];
      });
    } catch (e, s) {
      print('login error: $e - stack: $s');

      setState(() {
        isBusy = false;
        isLoggedIn = false;
        errorMessage = e.toString();
      });
    }
  }
```

And the lines that are erroring are;

`name = parseIdToken['name'];`

`picture = getUserDetails['picture'];`

Can this be fixed?

Comment: These are functions, you need to call them with the proper parameter, and then you can use [] to get part of the json returned. Like `getUserDetails(token)['picture']`. But it is better to store it in a variable first, because you function result can be null and that will throw a runtime error.

Answer (score -1):

`getUserDetails` is a function, and so it doesn't have a `[]` operator.

Instead, try: `var userDetails = await getUserDetails("token...");  picture = userDetails["picture"];`